# Connecting an Excel Spreadsheet to R Shiny

Tags: r, excel, shiny

I'm relatively new to R. I am currently trying to make an app that takes a user's input through an R Shiny interface and copy it into an Excel spreadsheet called "DirectEffect". Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(xlsx)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput(inputId = "num", 
               label = "Choose a number",
               min = 0, max = 1000000, value = 1),
  actionButton(inputId = "submit", 
               label = "Submit")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  options(java.parameters = "- Xmx1024m")
  wb <- loadWorkbook(file = "F:\\RProject-Rough\\DirectEffect.xlsx")

sheet<-getSheets(wb)

  observeEvent(input$submit, 
        {
          addDataFrame(input$submit, sheet$'Direct Effects',col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, startRow = 3,startColumn=5)

saveWorkbook(wb,"F:\\RProject-Rough\\DirectEffect.xlsx")
         }
    )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

My problems are these:

- The code doesn't work; it neither generates an error or puts the value in the spreadsheet.
- It's really slow, and sometimes I get the "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded".

Can you see where my mistake is, and how I could fix it?

Comment: It works fine for me windows 7 with Java 1.8.0_74-b02 & R 3.3.1. Try updating packages `rJava`, `xlsxjars` and `xlsx`

Comment: @HubertL Hey, thanks for the help! I just updated the packages, but my Excel spreadsheet isn't getting updated. Do you have any advice for that?

Comment: @HubertL Never mind! I figured it out thanks to you. I wanted the recorded value to be the one I inputted into the app. However, what happened was the number of clicks was recorded instead. I didn't realize this because the number increased by one each time I checked. (I was looking for huge differences because I was inputting huge numbers.) I changed "input$submit" to "input$num", and it worked out. Small mistake. Thank you for your help again!

Comment: No problem! Good you found the mistake. Just delete the question then.